# How to deep link to youtube in tvOS

Tags: ios, youtube, tvos, deep-linking

I am trying to deep-link to youtube movies/videos in Apple TV.
I am able to make it work in iOS devices with the following URL.

"youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKFuXETZUsI".

This works fine in iOS but it just launches the app and doesn't deep link to the content in tvOS.

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for same, Could you please share deep-link if you have solution for this?